# How to output error record as part of DB2 Stored Procedure standard output

Tags: stored-procedures, error-handling, db2-luw

Sometimes when we execute the error record we get bad data and the below stored procedure errors out with error code as

***"sql> call REFLOADER.SP_ALL_ES_CODE()
[2018-11-20 10:14:01] [22004][-87] A null value was specified in a context where a null value is not allowed.. SQLCODE=-87, SQLSTATE=22004, DRIVER=4.23.42".***

**As such I would like to **split out the error code along with the error values/record set that is failing in the below script**. can you please help with the code where and how can i get the error record output.**

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SCHEMA1.SP_ALL_CODE ()
DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1
P1: BEGIN

```
      DECLARE SQLSTATE CHAR(5) DEFAULT '00000';
  
      DECLARE l_stmt VARCHAR(5000);
      DECLARE l_dynamic_sql VARCHAR(5000);
        DECLARE l_uuid CHAR(36);
        DECLARE     l_ID VARCHAR(255); 
        DECLARE     l_table VARCHAR(100); 
        DECLARE     l_exists integer;
        DECLARE     l_changed integer;
        DECLARE     l_CID VARCHAR(255);
        DECLARE     l_Tt VARCHAR(255);
        DECLARE     l_TL VARCHAR(255);
        DECLARE     l_DateStart DATE;
        DECLARE     l_DateEnd DATE;
        DECLARE     l_DateEnd_Format DATE;
  
  P2: BEGIN
        -- Declare cursor
        DECLARE cursor1 CURSOR WITH RETURN TO CLIENT FOR
        SELECT c.ID , REPLACE(CID,'''',''''''), REPLACE(tt,'''',''''''), TL ,DateStart ,DateEnd , tablename
        FROM SCHEMA1.ALL_CODE c, SCHEMA1.ID_TABLENAME t
        WHERE c.id = t.id  
        and t.tabletype = 1 
        -- Access Location/Site (ignore end dated)
        --and (c.oid != '2.16.840.1.113883.3.2390.2.2.26' OR DateEnd is null)
        and (t.tablename != 'FREQUENCY' OR DateEnd is null)
        and (t.tablename != 'ORDER_FREQUENCY' OR DateEnd is null)
        Order By c.ID , CID;
  
        -- Cursor left open for client application
        OPEN cursor1;
        FETCH FROM cursor1 INTO 
                    l_ID , l_CID , l_Tt , l_TL , l_DateStart , l_DateEnd, l_table ;
      
      WHILE(SQLSTATE = '00000')
      DO
          --Insert or Update
          IF (l_DateStart IS NULL) THEN 
              SET l_DateStart = '1900-01-01';
          END IF;
          
          --exception
              -- L_TEST (smart) 216840
                    If l_id = '216840' Then
                          SET l_CID = LPAD(l_CID,4,'0' );     
                    End if;

          
            SET l_exists = 0;
            SET l_dynamic_sql = 'select count(*) from m_ref.' || l_table || ' where c_id =' || '''' || l_id || ':' || l_cId || '''' ;
            --INSERT INTO SCHEMA1.dml_ins_upd VALUES (l_dynamic_sql);
             PREPARE p_exist_cursor from l_dynamic_sql;
  
  P3: BEGIN
             DECLARE exist_cursor CURSOR FOR p_exist_cursor;
             OPEN exist_cursor;
             FETCH exist_cursor INTO l_exists;
             CLOSE exist_cursor;
  END P3;
              
              IF (l_exists = 0)
              THEN
                  SET l_uuid = RANDOMUUID();
                  SET l_stmt = 'Insert into SCHEMA1.' || l_table ||
                               ' (ID, CID, DISPLAY_NAME, END_DATE, START_DATE) values (' || 
                               '''' || l_uuid  || '''' || ',' ||
                               '''' || l_oid || ':' || l_cId  || '''' || ',' ||
                               '''' || l_Tt     || '''' || ',';
                                       
                    IF (l_DateEnd IS NULL) THEN
                          SET l_stmt = l_stmt || 'NULL' || ',' ;
                    ELSE
                          SET l_stmt = l_stmt || '''' || VARCHAR_FORMAT(l_DateEnd, 'YYYY-MM-DD')        || '''' || ',' ;
                    END IF;
                    
                    SET l_stmt = l_stmt || '''' || VARCHAR_FORMAT(l_DateStart, 'YYYY-MM-DD')     || '''' || ');' ;
                    
                    if (l_stmt is null) then
                             set l_stmt = 'YYY';
                          end if;
                    INSERT INTO SCHEMA1.dml_ins_upd VALUES (l_stmt);
              
                    -- Exceptions
                    -- CC
                    If l_table = 'CARECAT' Then
                          SET l_stmt = 'Update SCHEMA1.CARE_CATEGORY SET CONTEXT_NAME = ' || '''' || 'NOTE'       || '''';        
                          SET l_stmt = l_stmt || ' WHERE cid = ' || '''' || (l_id || ':' || l_cId) || '''' || ';' ;
        
                          if (l_stmt is null) then
                             set l_stmt = 'BBB';
                          end if;
                            INSERT INTO REFLOADER.dml_ins_upd VALUES (l_stmt);
                    End if;
                    -- LTEST (Test) 2168401
                    If l_id = '2168401' Then
                          SET l_stmt = 'Update SCHEMA1.LTEST SET IS_FLAG = 0';     
                          SET l_stmt = l_stmt || ' WHERE code_id = ' || '''' || (l_id || ':' || l_cId) || '''' || ';' ;
                          
                                if (l_stmt is null) then
                                         set l_stmt = 'XXX';
                                end if;
                            INSERT INTO REFLOADER.dml_ins_upd VALUES (l_stmt);
                    End if;
                    -- LAB_TEST (Panel) 2168401
                    If l_id = '2168401' Then
                          SET l_stmt = 'Update SCHEMA1.LTEST SET IS_FLAG = 1';     
                          SET l_stmt = l_stmt || ' WHERE code_id = ' || '''' || (l_id || ':' || l_cId) || '''' || ';' ;
                                if (l_stmt is null) then
                                         set l_stmt = 'TTT';
                                end if;
                            INSERT INTO SCHEMA1.dml_ins_upd VALUES (l_stmt);
                    End if;
              ------------------------------
            END IF;
            
            IF (l_exists != 0)
            THEN
              SET l_changed = 0;
              SET l_dynamic_sql = 'select count(*) ' ||
                                            ' from SCHEMA1.' || l_table ||
                                            ' where cid = ' || '''' || l_id || ':' || l_cId || '''' ;    
                                            
              if (l_termshort is null) then                             
                    SET l_dynamic_sql = l_dynamic_sql ||
                                            ' and   (display_name != null ';
              else
                    SET l_dynamic_sql = l_dynamic_sql ||
                                            ' and   (display_name != '  || '''' || l_tt || '''' ;                       
              end if;
              
              --Exception FREQUENCY
              If (l_table = 'FREQUENCY') Then
                  if (l_tl is null) then                             
                        SET l_dynamic_sql = l_dynamic_sql ||
                                                ' OR numeric_value is not null ';
                  else
                        SET l_dynamic_sql = l_dynamic_sql ||
                                                ' OR numeric_value is null ' ||
                                                ' OR numeric_value != ' || l_tl  ;                       
                  end if;
              End IF;
              ---
                                         
              SET l_dynamic_sql = l_dynamic_sql ||
                                            ' OR date(start_date) != '  || '''' || VARCHAR_FORMAT(l_DateStart, 'YYYY-MM-DD') || '''' ;
                                            
              if (l_DateEnd is null) then
                SET l_dynamic_sql = l_dynamic_sql ||  ' OR end_date is not null';
              else
                SET l_dynamic_sql = l_dynamic_sql ||  ' OR end_date is null OR date(end_date) != '  || '''' || VARCHAR_FORMAT(l_DateEnd, 'YYYY-MM-DD') || '''' ;
              end if;                             
                                            
              SET l_dynamic_sql = l_dynamic_sql || ')';

             --INSERT INTO REFLOADER.dml_ins_upd VALUES (l_dynamic_sql);
             PREPARE p_changed_cursor from l_dynamic_sql;
  P4: BEGIN
             DECLARE change_cursor CURSOR FOR p_changed_cursor;
             OPEN change_cursor;
             FETCH change_cursor INTO l_changed;
             CLOSE change_cursor;
  END P4;
    
            IF (l_changed = 1)
            THEN
                    SET l_stmt = 'Update SCHEMA1.' || l_table || ' SET display_name = ' || '''' || l_TS       || '''' || ',';   
                    
                    --Exception FREQUENCY
                      If (l_table = 'FREQUENCY') Then
                          IF (l_TL IS NULL) THEN
                                SET l_stmt = l_stmt || ' numeric_value = ' || 'NULL' || ',' ;
                          ELSE
                                SET l_stmt = l_stmt || ' numeric_value = ' || l_tl || ',' ;
                          END IF;
                      End IF;
                    ---
                           
                         IF (l_DateEnd IS NULL) THEN
                                SET l_stmt = l_stmt || ' end_date = ' || 'NULL' || ',' ;
                          ELSE
                                SET l_stmt = l_stmt || ' end_date = ' || '''' || VARCHAR_FORMAT(l_DateEnd, 'YYYY-MM-DD')        || '''' || ',' ;
                          END IF;
                      SET l_stmt = l_stmt || ' start_date = ' || '''' || VARCHAR_FORMAT(l_DateStart, 'YYYY-MM-DD')     || ''''  ;        
                    SET l_stmt = l_stmt || ' WHERE cid = ' || '''' || (l_id || ':' || l_cId) || '''' || ';' ;
  
                          if (l_stmt is null) then
                             set l_stmt = 'XXX';
                          end if;
                      INSERT INTO SCHEMA1.dml_ins_upd VALUES (l_stmt);
              END IF;
          END IF;
          -- Fetch Next
            FETCH FROM cursor1 INTO 
                    l_ID , l_CID , l_Tt , l_TL , l_DateStart , l_DateEnd,  l_table;
              
       END WHILE;
       CLOSE cursor1;
  
  END P2;
       commit work;
  END P1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your tool must be able to display so called [SQLCA structure](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.sqlpl.doc/doc/c0060679.html) returned by the database manager on your statement. DB2 Command Line Processor displays this structure with '-a' parameter. The line of code with an error is in the sqlerrd(3) field (see the example at the link).